# Hyperlink masquerading as an unwanted relative

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, express

I'm having a weird bug and I'm stumped.

On my web page I have

```
<a href="www.purple.com">Purple</a>
```

but when clicked it behaves as

```
<a href="http://mydomain.com/www.purple.com">Purple</a>
```

However, when I view source it is just as it should be. The links are being added dynamically in a chat application using markdown syntax. Therefore it isn't a simple solution of adding http:// to everything. Is there another way to fix this?

**EDIT**

I've been able to hack around it using a javascript replace() to add in a http:// at the beginning of every link, but I am still wondering if there is an easier, more graceful solution.

```
msg = msg.replace(/href="/ig, 'href="http://').replace(/http:\/\/http:\/\//ig, 'http://')
```

Answer (score 2):

If you do not prepend a `http://` for your external links, they'll be treated as links from your domain itself - relative to the path where the calling document resides or the path specified in your base href.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can't edit or troubleshoot the markdown syntax (that's ... apparently generating the string in the first place), you can use jQuery to put a band-aid on the fix. Again, this isn't really preferred...

```
$("a[href*='http://mydomain.com/www']").each(function(i, el){
    //this will iterate through all links with an href
    //value that contains the above string 'http://mydomain.com/www'

    var old_url = $(el).attr('href');
    var new_url = old_url.split('http://mydomain.com/')[1]; //split up the url, and correct the mistake

    $(el).attr('href', new_url);//re-apply the href attribute to the element
});
```

Comment: yeah, the links are dynamic so that wouldn't work...I did a simple replace server side